# template inside template VS 2005 issue?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2005

Code below (it compiled fine with clang and gcc). The question is this code violate of C++03 standard,
or this is VS 2005 bug? And if this is the bug, any work around?

**Update: I found workaround, by using forward declaration:**

```
//forward declaration
template<typename T, bool IsAcceptedType = Filter::template Acceptor<T>::IsAccepted>
struct FilteredConstructor;

//implementation
template<typename T>
class FilteredConstructor<T, true> {/*code here*/};
```

**But question about valid or not valid such code acording to standard still here**

```
namespace {
    struct CoreTypesFilter {
        template<typename T> struct Acceptor {
           static const bool IsAccepted = false;
        };
    };
}


template<class Filter>
class QVariantConstructor {
    template<typename T, bool IsAcceptedType = Filter::template Acceptor<T>::IsAccepted>
    struct FilteredConstructor {
       FilteredConstructor(const QVariantConstructor &tc) {}
    };

    template<typename T>
    struct FilteredConstructor<T, /* IsAcceptedType = */ false> {
        FilteredConstructor(const QVariantConstructor &tc) {}
    };
public:
    template<typename T>
    void delegate(const T*)
    {
        FilteredConstructor<T> tmp(*this);
    }
};
//comment or uncomment them to build on VS or linux
#define _TCHAR char
#define _tmain main

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    QVariantConstructor<CoreTypesFilter> vc;
    vc.delegate("test");//this line trigger compile error
    return 0;
}
```

Compilation errors from VS 2005 compiler:

```
error C2976: 'QVariantConstructor::FilteredConstructor' : too few template arguments

1>        with
1>        [
1>            Filter=`anonymous-namespace'::CoreTypesFilter
1>        ]
1>        see declaration of 'QVariantConstructor::FilteredConstructor'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            Filter=`anonymous-namespace'::CoreTypesFilter
1>        ]
1>        see reference to function template instantiation 'void QVariantConstructor::delegate(const T *)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            Filter=`anonymous-namespace'::CoreTypesFilter,
1>            T=char
1>        ]
1>        error C2514: 'QVariantConstructor::FilteredConstructor' : class has no constructors
1>        with
1>        [
1>            Filter=`anonymous-namespace'::CoreTypesFilter
1>        ]
1>       see declaration of 'QVariantConstructor::FilteredConstructor'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            Filter=`anonymous-namespace'::CoreTypesFilter
1>        ]
```

Comment: It compiles on VS2013, maybe it's a bug.

Comment: What _line_ generates the error message?

Comment: This isn't the problem, but names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter (`_TCHAR`) and names that contain two consecutive underscores are reserved to the implementation. Don't use them.

Comment: I not use them, this is generated by VS 2005 code. I add defines to compile on linux with gcc/clang.

Comment: I add comment in code about which line trigger compile error.

Comment: Vs2005 is 8 years old. Update to a newer compiler!

Comment: @MikeVine: "8 years old" Bad argument. Software doesn't rot. Now if VS2005 had a critical bug of some sort that is fixed in newer version...

Comment: @SigTerm Visual Studio has many compiler bugs over the years, especially with complex template codes.

Answer (score 0):

I had a quick read through the relevant section of the standard, and the issue appears to come down to how you read ISO/IEC 14882:2003 section 14.1 paragraph 9

A default template-argument is a `template-argument` (14.3) specified after `=` in a `template-parameter`. A default `template-argument` may be specified for any kind of `template-parameter` (type, non-type, template). A default `template-argument` may be specified in a class template declaration or a class template definition. A default `template-argument` ***shall not be specified*** in a function template declaration or a function template definition, ***nor in the `template-parameter-list` of the definition of a member of a class template***. A default `template-argument` shall not be specified in a friend template declaration.

Strictly speaking this appears to imply that your code is illegal. However it appears that most implementations interpret this to mean *definitions of an already declared template member*.

Health warning, this is based on a first reading. My answer may well be wrong or incomplete, please correct me.